# Finding daily returns in R for multiple columns and rows

Tags: r, time-series

I have this dataframe called finaldf which looks like this with a Total of 70 different crypto currency prices and data for around 2 to 3 years

```
Date        P1          P2      P3     P4...........P70      
28-Apr-13   135.3       135.98  132.1  134.2
29-Apr-13   134.44      147.49  134    144.54  
30-Apr-13   144         146.93  134.05 139    
1-May-13    139         139.89  107.72 116.99
```

I want to apply a formula to all the P1 to P70 for daily return. For example the formula i want to apply based on the example data will look like (134.44-135.3)/135.3 but it will cover all the data from P1 to P70 for all dates. The Final Output i am looking for will be somewhat like this

DR = Daily Return

```
Date  P1  DR1  P2  DR2.......P70  DR70
```

Comment: Try with `liibrary(dplyr);df1 %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with('P')), funs(DR = (lead(.)- .)/.))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mutate_at` from `dplyr` to specify the columns that start with 'P' and divide the successive values with the current values to create the 'DR' columns

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with('P')), funs(DR = (lead(.)- .)/.))
```